# Function that takes templated length parameter

Tags: c++, templates

I have a custom array class

```
template <typename T, unsigned L>
class Array
{
    T m_buff[L];
};
```

My goal is to declare a function that would take a copy of the Array class and use its values to return a sum of all elements.
The problem is that the code compiles only for a function defined as `int sum(Array<int, 3> a)` and not for a function defined as `int sum(Array<int> a)`.

Comment: `template<typename T, unsigned L> T sum(const Array<T,L> &array) { /* calc, return sum */}`.          You might want to consider using types from the standard library (e.g. the templated `std::array`) and standard algorithms (e.g. `std::accumulate()`) to add up elements of one.

Comment: I'm aware of the standard array implementation, but I want to make my own one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> not for a function defined as int sum(Array a).

That's because `Array<int>` is not a valid type. Your `Array` template requires two parameters, not one.

What you are looking for, simply, is just another template function:

```
template<unsigned size> int sum(const Array<int, size> &a)
{
   // Function code here:
}
```

As far how to code it: simply think of what your code needs to be, in case of your `Array<int, 3>`, or, maybe, `Array<int, 100000>` and replace `3` or `100000` with `size`/